# GitHub Pull Request Builder not building Xcode 7.2.1 in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, xcode7, pull-request

I have the **GitHub Pull Request Builder** configured properly in Jenkins and is working as expected. I added a shell to execute **swiftlint** as the passing criteria and that works as expected. However, we found a problem where the code passed linting, but did got stuck using the xcodebuild command line as a second step of instructions. So we added linting into the runtime of the build and when we try to run `xcodebuild -workspace MYPROJECT.xcworkspace -scheme MYPROJECT -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5,OS=8.1' clean build` when a PR is detected. it just sits there and spins unless I put an abort time on the job. When i try this in the terminal locally it works and it works if I put it in a job that doesn't contain the **GitHub Pull Request Builder**

Answer (score 0):

By using `open -a xcode ${WORKSPACE}/MYPROJECT.xcworkspace` I discovered that Xcode was waiting for a prompt to be resolved

> Automatically Create Schemes

Unreal, you would never know that if you were working from a remote location and didn't have screen access. Either way, everything works as expected now.